# abstract base class extension

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Here is my simplified code which requires your valuable comments about poorly implemented polymorphism.

```
class X
{
    public:
        void test();
    protected:
        virtual void foo() const = 0;
};


class Y : public X
{
    public:
        void foo(){ cout << "hello" << endl; }
};


int main()
{   
    X *obj = new Y();
}
```

I get the following error at compilation.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:23: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Y’
test.cpp:14: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Y’:
test.cpp:9: note:   virtual void X::foo() const
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
class Y : public X
{
    public:
        void foo() const { cout << "hello" << endl; }
};
```

Because

```
void foo() const
```

and

```
void foo()
```

are not the same function.

Answer (score 2):

`foo` funciton in class Y has different signature with X::foo

```
class Y : public X
{
  public:
    void foo() const { cout << "hello" << endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`foo` in class Y is not const, so you are not overloading the virtual in class X.